# TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: node.js, image, file-upload, express, multipartform-data

There is something wrong in my source code but I'm not able to figure out what - please help. I was looking for some solutions found some and updated source code according them but didn't help.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var form = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>" +
"<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
"<input type='file' name='image' id='image'/>" +
"<input type='submit' /></form>" +
"</body></html>";



app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(form);

});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function(err, data){

        var imageName = req.files.image.name
        if(!imageName){
            console.log("There was an error");
            res.redirect('/');
            res.end();
        }else{
            var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName;

            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err){
                res.redirect("/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName);
            });
        }

    });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: try `req.body.files` instead of `req.files`. If you're sending some data from an HTTP request it would be stored in the request body. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625519/how-to-access-the-request-body-when-posting-using-node-js-and-express

Comment: Same problem still - when I have put on console req.body it's empty. Please note that it's multipart not json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `body-parser` middleware does not handle `multipart` bodies.

From the `body-parser` github:

```
This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large
nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:
```

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)
- [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser